# Assigning 64-bit values under -pedantic-errors

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I recently tried to solve [Project Euler problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) using [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/) and I noticed something strange.
As codepad used the flag `-pedantic-errors`, I couldn't use `long long` to store my number, but I noticed that I still could use `uint64_t`.

Here begins my problem.
Whereas I could define a variable as `uint64_t`, I had no good way of actually assigning the value.
I could assign the value in ugly ways (avert your eyes):

```
// This is very ugly code:
uint64_t s = 600851;
s *= 1000000;
s += 475143;

cout << "s = " << s << endl;
```

but I could not do a straight assignment like so:

```
// This gives me errors:
uint64_t s = 600851475143ULL;
```

Probably as it first interprets the right side as a `long long`.

So how is assignment actually supposed to work in this case?
Is it just a loophole that I can access the type, but not assign anything?
Are there any good workarounds if that's the case?

Comment: The code works well on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V0FpWPRphJlrgDtB) with proper compiler setting. Must you use codepad? If not, I suggest you should use another compiler because the compiler used on codepad is a little bit old.

Comment: If we look at the [about section](http://codepad.org/about) it is using an ancient gcc and using `-std=c++98`. Unless you need to use these settings I would use wandbox or coliru.

Comment: I didn't have to use codebox, so thanks for the alternate site.  However, the point of the question was to find out if there was a different way to assign values that I don't know about or if there really is no good way to assign 64-bit values under those circumstances.